# Does the order of sections in readme.txt matter?

Tags: plugin-development, readme

As the title says, *Does the order of sections in readme.txt matter?*

This relates to me editing changelog every update and having to scroll past all the FAQ entries.

Is it OK to move changelog to the top of readme.txt to make my life just that little bit easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only header ( === Plugin name === ) and short description ( in that order ) must be on top. Other sections ( == section == ) can be placed in any order. Your == Changelog == can go just below short description, not higher.